# How to catch configuration binding exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, .net-core, configuration

I am building a console application in .NET Core 2.2.

I added strongly-typed configuration like this:

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();

services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(configuration);
```

My configuration is bound to an object of class `AppConfiguration`. I wonder, how can I catch exceptions that could happen while binding config values to my class? For example, one of my configuration properties is an enum. If user provides nonexisting parameter, I get exception with stack trace:

> at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean
>   ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)    at System.Enum.Parse(Type
>   enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)

Basically, I need some way to know that exception happened because of wrong configuration and not some other problem. If I was able to catch any configuration binding-related exceptions, I could throw my own WrongConfigurationException to catch it and be sure that something was wrong with config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fail early by eagerly getting/binding the desired object from configuration and catching any exceptions thrown during startup.

Reference [Bind to an object graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-to-an-object-graph)

```
//...

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();

try {
    //bind to object graph
    AppConfiguration appConfig = configuration.Get<AppConfiguration>();

    //custom validation can be done here as well
    //...        

    //if valid add to service collection.
    services.AddSingleton(appConfig);    
} catch(Exception ex) {
    throw new WrongConfigurationException("my message here", ex);
}

//...
```

Note that with the above example the class can be explicitly injected into dependents without having to be wrapped in [`IOptions<T>`, which has its own design implications](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servicecollectionintegration.html#working-with-ioptions-t)

The try-catch can also be foregone by just letting it fail at that point.

```
//...

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true)
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();


//bind to object graph
AppConfiguration appConfig = configuration.Get<AppConfiguration>();

//custom validation can be done here as well
if(/*conditional appConfig*/)
    throw new WrongConfigurationException("my message here");

//if valid add to service collection.
services.AddSingleton(appConfig);    

//...
```

It should easily indicate where and why the exception was thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I created ConfigureationProvider that builds configuration, validates it and registers in serviceCollection. If something goes wrong during the process, it throws WrongConfigurationException.