# Configuration binding exception in array not catched?

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, configuration

Exception from an array in a configuration does not get passed through?! For 1 dimensional configuration this is working (as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974195/how-to-catch-configuration-binding-exception)). But when more dimensional configurations are used the exception will be ignored as you can see in the following example:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Value": 1,
  "ArrayValue": [
    { "Value":  0 }
  ]
}
```

**Config.cs**

```cs
class Config
{
  private int value;

  public int Value
  {
    get => this.value;
    set
    {
        if (value < 1)
            throw new NullReferenceException();     // ExceptionType only for testing purpose

        this.value = value;
    }
  }

  public IEnumerable<ConfigArray> ArrayValue { get; set; }
}

class ConfigArray
{
  private int arrayValue;

  public int ArrayValue
  {
    get => this.arrayValue;
    set
    {
        if (value < 1)
            throw new NullReferenceException();     // ExceptionType only for testing purpose

        this.arrayValue = value;
    }
  }
}
```

**Program snippet**

```
Config config;

try
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)
        .Build();

    config = configuration.Get<Config>();
    //config = new Config();
    //configuration.Bind(config);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
}
```

**Packages**

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="3.1.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.6" />
```

The exception in the ConfigArray is not bypassed to the main program. Am I missing something or are exceptions in arrays generally ignored by the configuration binder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution i found is to create a property that determines if an error occurs.

Possible solution:

**Config.cs**

```cs
// If more than one error is possible, it can be a better solution to generate error codes
enum ErrorCode
{
  OK,
  ERROR
}

class Config
{
  private int value;
  private IEnumerable<ConfigArray> configArray;

  public int Value
  {
    get => this.value;
    set
    {
      if (value < 1)
        throw new NullReferenceException();     // ExceptionType only for testing purpose

      this.value = value;
    }
  }


  public IEnumerable<ConfigArray> ArrayValue
  {
    get => this.configArray;
    set
    {
      value.ToList().ForEach(c =>
      {
        switch (c.Error)
        {
          case ErrorCode.ERROR:
            throw new NullReferenceException();
          default:
            break;
        }   
      });

      this.configArray = value;
    }
  }
}

class ConfigArray
{
  private int arrayValue;

  public int ArrayValue
  {
    get => this.arrayValue;
    set
    {
      this.Error = ErrorCode.OK;

      if (value < 1)
        this.Error = ErrorCode.ERROR;

      this.arrayValue = value;
    }
  }

  public ErrorCode Error { get; private set; }
}
```

**Program Snippet**

```cs
Config config = null;

try
{
  IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, false)
      .Build();

  config = configuration.Get<Config>();
  //config = new Config();
  //configuration.Bind(config);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  if(ex.InnerException is Exception)
      Console.WriteLine($"Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}");

  Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
}
```

Maybe there are some better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

See here for more information.
[Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs)

```cs
private static Array BindArray(Array source, IConfiguration config, BinderOptions options)
{
    IConfigurationSection[] children = config.GetChildren().ToArray();
    int arrayLength = source.Length;
    Type elementType = source.GetType().GetElementType();
    var newArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, arrayLength + children.Length);

    // binding to array has to preserve already initialized arrays with values
    if (arrayLength > 0)
    {
        Array.Copy(source, newArray, arrayLength);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < children.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            object item = BindInstance(
                type: elementType,
                instance: null,
                config: children[i],
                options: options);
                
            if (item != null)
            {
                newArray.SetValue(item, arrayLength + i);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

As you can see in the code above, we catch and grip the exception.
Therefore, it is necessary to take actions like the one taken by [sunriax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13855290/sunriax).